# Update popupmenu list

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have to delete an element form the popupmenu and update it with this code :

```
tmps=get(handles.popupmenu2,'string')
x=find(strcmp(item ,list)) % x is the position of the item i want to delete it from the list 
list = list(~strcmp(list, list{x})) % delete the item from the list
set(handles.popupmenu2,'string',list)
```

The code work properly if you delete any element, but if you delete the last item before the first items the popupmenu will disappear and you get this error:

```
Warning: 'popupmenu' control requires a non-empty String
Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid
```

Comment: hum, I can't find nothing that will make `cell(var)` output `array`. I though about differences between cell array and vector, but i am not sure if thats your problem. But remember, `a={things}` is a **cell array** in matlab, not an array only (it may lead to confusion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it : 
The value for popupmenu2 must be set to a "common" index before setting the string property. In this case, the common index is 1. so i needed to redefine the value before update it like this :

```
tmps=get(handles.popupmenu2,'string')
x=find(strcmp(item ,list)) % x is the position of the item i want to delete it from the list 
list = list(~strcmp(list, list{x})) % delete the item from the list
set(handles.popupmenu2, 'value', 1);
set(handles.popupmenu2,'string',list)
```